# List not updating and appears to looping my Python code for pcap analysis

Tags: python, list, loops, pcap

I have been trying to extract emails from a pcap file and add them to a list. I have tried every way I can think off but can't seem to output it in any other way than what looks like a loop.

---

```
def email_list(info):
    #print('[+] email addresses found: ')
    list = []
    emaillist = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.\w{2,4}", info)
    for em in emaillist:
        list.append(em)
        print(list)
```

---

Sample output

---

```
['simonbrew@hotmail.com']
['samson@infoworld.com']
['brianjungman@gmail.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
['inter0pt1c@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com', 'inter0pt1c@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com', 'inter0pt1c@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
['d4rktangent@gmail.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com', 'd4rktangent@gmail.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com', 'd4rktangent@gmail.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
['mistersekritx@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com', 'mistersekritx@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com', 'mistersekritx@aol.com']
```

---

The idea is, I want to find the emails, add them to a list, remove duplicates and then print them out in a nice table format.

This is all my code so far.

---

```
import dpkt,socket,datetime,geoip2.database,re,sys,urllib.request,urllib
from tabulate import tabulate
from collections import Counter
from prettytable import PrettyTable


def packet_type(pcap):
    ####https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18256342/parsing-a-pcap-file-in-python####
    other = []
    IP = []
    tcp = []
    udp = []
    igmp = []

    for ts, buf in pcap:
        # Unpack the Ethernet frame (mac src/dst, ethertype)
        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
        #print(f'#<INFO> eth ethernet packet: {repr(eth)}')
        # ip address
        ip = eth.data
        # Extract TCP Payload
        TCP = ip.data
        info = repr(TCP)
        # read the source IP in dst
        src = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
        # read the destination IP in dst
        dst = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)
        try:
            if eth.type != dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP:
                other.append(src)
            IP.append(ip.len)
            if ip.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_IGMP:
                igmp.append(ip.len)
            elif ip.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP:
                tcp.append(ip.len)
            elif ip.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_UDP:
                udp.append(ip.len)
        except Exception as err:
            print(f'Oh no there has been an {err}')
            continue
    timestamp(tcp,udp,igmp)



def timestamp(tcp,udp,igmp):
    tcp.sort()
    Tcp = len(tcp)
    TCP1st = tcp[0]
    TCP2nd = tcp[-1]
    TCPts = str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(TCP1st))
    TCP2ts = str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(TCP2nd))
    udp.sort()
    Udp = len(udp)
    UDP = udp[0]
    UDP2nd = udp[-1]
    UDPts = str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(UDP))
    UDP2ts = str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(UDP2nd))
    igmp.sort()
    Igmp = len(igmp)
    IGMP = igmp[0]
    IGMP2nd = igmp[-1]
    IGMPts = str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(IGMP))
    IGMP2ts = str(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(IGMP2nd))
    mean_packet_length(tcp,udp,igmp,TCPts,TCP2ts,UDPts,UDP2ts,IGMPts,IGMP2ts,Tcp,Udp,Igmp)


def mean_packet_length(tcp,udp,igmp,TCPts,TCP2ts,UDPts,UDP2ts,IGMPts,IGMP2ts,Tcp,Udp,Igmp):
    tcpmean = sum(tcp) / len(tcp)
    tcp_mean = round(tcpmean)
    udpmean = sum(udp) / len(udp)
    udp_mean = round(udpmean)
    igmpmean = sum(igmp) / len(igmp)
    igmp_mean = round(igmpmean)
    tabulate_table(tcp_mean,udp_mean,igmp_mean,TCPts,TCP2ts,UDPts,UDP2ts,IGMPts,IGMP2ts,Tcp,Udp,Igmp)


def tabulate_table(tcp_mean,udp_mean,igmp_mean,TCPts,TCP2ts,UDPts,UDP2ts,IGMPts,IGMP2ts,Tcp,Udp,Igmp):
    table =[['TCP',Tcp,TCPts,TCP2ts,tcp_mean], ['UDP',Udp,UDPts, UDP2ts, udp_mean], ['IGMP',Igmp,IGMPts,IGMP2ts,igmp_mean]]
    headers = ['Protocol','Count', 'First_Timestamp', 'Last_Timestamp', 'Mean_Length']
    print(tabulate(table, headers, tablefmt='fancy_grid'))
    tcp()


def email_list(info):
    #print('[+] email addresses found: ')
    list = []
    emaillist = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.\w{2,4}", info)
    for em in emaillist:
        list.append(em)
        print(list)


def tcp():
    with open(r'C:\Users\snoopgrapes\Desktop\evidence-packet-analysis.pcap', 'rb') as pcapfile:
        pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(pcapfile)
        for ts, buf in pcap:

            # Unpack the Ethernet frame (mac src/dst, ethertype)
            eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
            #print(f'#<INFO> eth ethernet packet: {repr(eth)}')
            # ip address
            ip = eth.data
            # Extract TCP Payload
            TCP = ip.data
            info = repr(TCP)
            email_list(info)


def find_uri():
    found = False
    gif_uri = []
    with open(r'C:\Users\snoopgrapes\Desktop\evidence-packet-analysis.pcap', 'rb') as pcapfile:
        pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(pcapfile)
        for ts, buf in pcap:
            try:
                eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)
                ip = eth.data
                tcp = ip.data
                http = dpkt.http.Request(tcp.data)
                if http.method == 'GET':
                    uri = http.uri.lower()
                    if '.gif' in uri:
                        gif_uri.append(uri)
                        found = True
            except Exception:
                pass
    print(f'Gif URI {gif_uri}')


def main():

    pcapFile = r'C:\Users\snoopgrapes\Desktop\evidence-packet-analysis.pcap'
    #pcapFile = r'C:\Users\snoopgrapes\Desktop\filtered2.pcap'
    #pcapFile = r'C:\Users\snoopgrapes\Desktop\filtered3.pcap'
    #pcapFile = r'C:\Users\snoopgrapes\Desktop\http.pcap'
    #pcapFile = r'C:\Users\snoopgrapes\Desktop\sampledata.pcap'
    #email = r'C:\Users\snoopgrapes\Desktop\email_sample.txt'
    excludesrc = '146.176.164.91'
    f = open(pcapFile, 'rb')
    pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)
    reader = geoip2.database.Reader('C:\Program Files\Python39\Geo\Geo.mmdb')
    print(f'[*] analysing {pcapFile} for packets not source {excludesrc}')
    print('------------------------------------------------------------')
    packet_type(pcap)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Thank you so much for any help

Answer (score 0):

```
list = []
emaillist = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.\w{2,4}", info)
for em in emaillist:
    list.append(em)
    print(list)
```

Basically you get a list of all emails in `emaillist`. Then you iterate over this `emaillist` and add each of the elements to `list`. But within each of the iterations you print everything which was collected so far, **including values you've already printed in the previous iteration**. What you likely tried to do is this (note the different indentation):

```
list = []
emaillist = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.\w{2,4}", info)
for em in emaillist:
    list.append(em)
print(list)
```

Or even more simple

```
list = re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.\w{2,4}", info)
print(list)
```

Comment: thanks. I have tried the ways suggested and this is what happens.... It looks like every time it adds an item it removes the previous item.....                                                                                                                    `[]
[]
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
['sneakyg33ky@aol.com', 'mistersekritx@aol.com']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]`

Comment: @snoopstargrapes: I have no idea what exact code produced what you show in your comment.

Answer (score -1):

```
def data(timestamp, ip):

    UDP, TCP = [], []
    UDP_Total, TCP_Total = 0, 0

    for timestamp, eth in zip(Array_Of_TimeStamp, Array_Of_IP):

        if eth.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP:
            TCP_Info.append(eth)
            TCP_TimeStamp_Info.append(timestamp)
            TCP_Total += 1
            TCP_len.append(len(TCP_Info))

        if eth.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_UDP:
            UDP_Info.append(eth)
            UDP_TimeStamp_Info.append(timestamp)
            UDP_Total += 1
            UDP_Len.append(len(UDP_Info))

    if TCP_TimeStamp_Info != 0:
        print(f"The Total amount of TCP Packets: {TCP_Total}")
        print(f"This is the First TCP Packet That was found: {datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(TCP_TimeStamp_Info[0])}")
        print(f"This is the Last TCP Packet That was found: {datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(TCP_TimeStamp_Info[-1])}")
        print(f"This Is The Legth of the packet: {mean(TCP_len)} \n")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It could also be improved by actually testing it. Don't compare arrays with numbers. Initialize your actual arrays, not random other variables.